# Confusion in window built in authentication (web.config)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config

I am currently working with my asp.net project. I use web.config settings to allow and deny services !

It works totaly fine ! Now I got some query ( just for knowledge) that if I use deny and allow authentication both what will happen ?

My code seems like that

```
<system.web>
     <authorization>
          <deny users="user_name" />
          <allow users="user_name" />
     </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Authorization elements are evaluated in the order they are given in the configuration file.

In your example, the user would be **denied**, as the `deny` entry is earlier in the list than the `allow` entry.

---

Note that your question is referring to ASP.NET URL Authorization Behaviour (i.e. the settings defined in `system.web\authorization`). The behaviour of IIS URL Authorization is quite different. See the "Differences Table" [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/142/understanding-iis-url-authorization/).

Comment: Errr... what behaviour are you attempting to achieve? Generally, you will only want 1 deny or 1 allow entry for any given user or group though.

Comment: Are I just post this question for information ! Just to increase my knowledge ! I have not applied both yet !

Comment: Ok - in that case, the important thing to know is that rules are evaluated in the order they appear in the config. Apply that rule to any questions you have and you should be fine :)